# How To Display Multiple Images At Runtime (Wraping to the next line)

Tags: java, android, imageview

I have a rather strange application where I will get the words/symbols at runtime and wont know them in advance.  I need to display them and word wrap the text when it is too wide for the display.

I am a little unsure what layout I should be using for this functionally but any hints would be greatly appreciated.  It would be nice if I could just add them to the card view and let it sort out the wrapping.  Is there a way to do this?

The code below should have displayed "This is a sentence put together dynamically at runtime".

[image: example output]

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="40dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:innerRadius="0dp"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="1.9"
        app:contentPadding="13dp"
        >


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                android:orientation="horizontal">

            </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);

        ImageView ivThis = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
        ivThis.setImageResource(R.drawable.word_this);
        ll.addView(ivThis);

        ImageView ivIs = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
        ivIs.setImageResource(R.drawable.word_is);
        ll.addView(ivIs);

        ImageView ivA = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
        ivA.setImageResource(R.drawable.word_a);
        ll.addView(ivA);

        ImageView ivSentance = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
        ivSentance.setImageResource(R.drawable.word_sentance);
        ll.addView(ivSentance);

        ImageView ivPut = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
        ivPut.setImageResource(R.drawable.word_put);
        ll.addView(ivPut);

        ImageView ivTogether = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
        ivTogether.setImageResource(R.drawable.word_together);
        ll.addView(ivTogether);

        ImageView ivDynamically = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
        ivDynamically.setImageResource(R.drawable.word_dynamically);
        ll.addView(ivDynamically);

        ImageView ivAt = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
        ivAt.setImageResource(R.drawable.word_at);
        ll.addView(ivAt);

        ImageView ivRuntime = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
        ivDynamically.setImageResource(R.drawable.word_runtime);
        ll.addView(ivRuntime);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this helps someone else out.  Below is how I got the functionality i was looking for.

Gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.1.0'
}
```

XML

```
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:flexWrap="wrap"
    app:alignItems="stretch"
    app:alignContent="stretch" >

</com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have a rather strange application where I will get the words/symbols
>   at runtime and wont know them in advance. I need to display them and
>   word wrap the text when it is too wide for the display.

Sounds like you're looking for a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) to display the data dynamically(at runtime).

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I am using a recyclerview.  I mocked up this simple example to show how the words (which are images) do not wrap to the next line.  The real issue that I am having is the wrapping of images.

Comment: use `layout_height` as `wrap_content`

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that again but the images do not wrap.  I set android:layout_height="wrap_content" on the card view and the Linearlayout.  I also tried to use a ConstraintLayout but all the images get drawn on top of one another.